# Mean of several rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a rather big dataframe for my calculation method (SSA) - about 80000 rows. I'd like to average my data by several rows (20 for example). How can I do this?

I have a dataframe, for example:

```
 1. 00h         03h         06h         09h         12h
10  0.003546    0.000885    0.006852    0.00171     0.001708
11  0.00667     0.012603    0.012933    0.05603     0.025855
12  0.089116    0.054549    0.022177    0.090342    0.070226
13  0.28974     0.246415    0.297231    0.399953    0.287122
```

And in the end, I'd like something like this:

[image: this]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer division by range created by length of DataFrame with [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).mean()
print (df)

        00h       03h       06h       09h       12h
0  0.005108  0.006744  0.009893  0.028870  0.013782
1  0.189428  0.150482  0.159704  0.245147  0.178674
```

Comment: And in the case of 80000 rows and 20ty-row averaging, I should use

df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//20).mean()  ?